# Dúvida sobre o corpo da requisição

Tags: node.js, express.js

Eu estava fazendo alguns testes e percebi que ao mandar um parâmetro com aspas simples e duplas, ocorre um erro interno.

Ex:

```js
password: teste'"
```

Erro:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\iarlo\Desktop\teste\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)    
    at parse (C:\Users\iarlo\Desktop\teste\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at C:\Users\iarlo\Desktop\teste\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\iarlo\Desktop\teste\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\iarlo\Desktop\teste\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\iarlo\Desktop\teste\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  expose: true,
  statusCode: 400,
  status: 400,
  body: 'invalid',
  type: 'entity.parse.failed'
}
```

Código:

```
import { body } from 'express-validator'
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get("/enviar", [
  body("password")
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage("Value cannot be empty")
    .isLength({ min: 6, max: 60 })
    .withMessage("Value must be between 6 and 60 characters long")
    .matches(
      new RegExp(
        "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])[\\w\\s!\"#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?@\\[\\]\\^_`{|}~]{6,}$",
        "i"
      )
    )
    .withMessage("Value is not a valid password"),
], (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
});
```

Requisição:
Content type: application/json

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como posso evitar que esse erro ocorra caso um usuário use as duas aspas numa mesma string? Ps. o erro ocorre antes que eu consiga dar `escape()`

Comment: Qual o código? Sua pergunta está com poucas informações.

Comment: O código é necessário? Quero dizer, minha dúvida é sobre como evitar que o usuário "injete" algo por meio desse erro. De qualquer maneira, como é possível ver na stack, o erro não tem raíz alguma no código, apenas no "node_modules/body-parser". Ele ocorre ao enviar uma requisição, antes mesmo de eu conseguir validar o corpo.

Comment: Você precisa criar um [mcve]. Sem ele, não somos capazes de reproduzir o seu problema...

Comment: Pode verificar agora?

Comment: Ok, eu mudei o content type para application/x-www-form-urlencoded e o erro desapareceu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o corpo da requisição normalmente é usado para uma lista de variáveis codificados em URI ou JSON

```
URI: var1=valor&var2=valor2
lembrando os nomes e valores de variaveis devem ser passados por encodeURIComponent antes de serem concatenados, para que os espaços, aspas e caracteres especiais sejam corretamente codificados
JSON: {"var1":"var2"}
```

no seu caso, o body-parser executou JSON.parse no body, que gerou um erro, por este corpo não ser um JSON válido, para evitar esté erro recomendo que um JSON.stringify no lado do frontend para converter um objeto em JSON válido...

caso queira validar seu JSON em uma ferramenta externa, indico:

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

lembrando que o JSON.parse também não aceita comentários, ou aspas simples, então recomendo sempre usar JSON.stringify.